# Howto create custom service in systemd?

Tags: bash, scripting, systemd, systemd-service

Running Fedora 33/34 on multiple machines.  I successfully activated `rc-local.service` which works fine.  I have couple of other scripts that I need to run in `/etc/init.d/` and I created similar service files as `rc-local.service`, but I can't enable it, whereas rc-local.service can be enabled/disabled/stared/stopped without any troubles.  
I know, that I have an option (which I currently use) to call those scripts from `rc.local` file, but would rather called them separately as service.  So my service file looks like this: 
`#cat net-scr1.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=Network check service
ConditionFileIsExecutable=/etc/init.d/net-scr1
After=network.target 

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/net-scr1 start
TimeoutSec=3
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/net-scr1 stop
RemainAfterExit=yes
GuessMainPID=no
StandardOutput=tty

[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`systemctl enable net-scr1`

```
Synchronizing state of net-scr1.service with SysV service script with /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable net-scr1
service net-scr1 does not support chkconfig
```

I moved the script out of `init.d` thinking maybe systemd assumes it's an old `sysv` script, but no change.  What should I have in my script to work properly? 
My script looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
EMFR=admin@server1.com
eml=admin@mydomain.com
dv0=p1p1
ipdv0=`ifconfig $dv0 | grep "inet " | awk '{print $2}'`
if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then
  cat $msg | mail $EMFR -s "$srv-shut_down-ip-$ipdv0" $eml
fi
if [ "$1" = "start" ]; then
  cat $msg | mail $EMFR -s "$srv-booted_up-ip-$ipdv0" $eml  

fi
```

Should I include Functions from the old sysv system or something else?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution.  I have included following 3 lines on top of my script: 
`head /etc/init.d/net-scr1`

```
# net-scr1          Start/Stop the net script1
# chkconfig: 345 90 10
# description: net-scr1 sends alert on reboot
```

now `systemctl enable net-scr1`  works fine

Comment: You're encouraged to mark your answer as the solution.

Comment: it doesn't let me for 2 days :)

Answer (score 0):

[See this](https://www.shubhamdipt.com/blog/how-to-create-a-systemd-service-in-linux/)

1. cd /etc/systemd/system
2. Create a file named your-service.service and include the following:

> ```
> [Unit]
> Description=<description about this service>
>
> [Service]
> User=<user e.g. root>
> WorkingDirectory=<directory_of_script e.g. /root>
> ExecStart=<script which needs to be executed>
> Restart=always
>
> [Install]
> WantedBy=multi-user.target
> ```

Comment: This is what I have done as you can see from my unit file.  but it doesn't want to enable service, as I posted above response.